# Translation of a math article from German

Tags: number-theory, translation-request, mathematical-german

Where could I find either a translation or an account of van der Waerden's arguments in his 1936 paper *Die Seltenheit der reduziblen Gleichungen und der Gleichungen mit Affekt*?

Comment: The paper is at http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01707594.

Comment: Indeed, but it's the German version... I would like an English or French version.